Roles/Permissions per tenant in Laravel/Filament
I am working on a multi-tenancy application in Filament and struggling with database design.
What I have done is that each user belongs to many tenants (Units in my case) and each tenant can have multiple users.
When creating an account, every user also creates a tenant (Unit), unless invited (through the dashboard) to already created Unit.
What I am trying to do is to introduce roles and permission so that each user gets a "owner" role
upon tenant creation, invited users should have "reader" role.
Which would mean that each user would have a role associated with the tenant (Unit).
I'm looking for a simple solution.
This is the current situation and I don't know if it is the best solution.



unit_user




user_id


unit_id


role_id






roles




id


name


descr



Now to fetch current role:
public function currentUnitRole()
{
        return $this->units()
            ->where('id', Filament::getTenant()->id)
            ->with('pivot.role') // Eager load the role relationship
            ->first()
            ->pivot
            ->role;
}

Is there a better way?

You can add a new role column to your unit_user table, this way for every user attached to a unit the role will tell you if they are the owner or a reader.
Once that is added you can use the relationship pivot option to access the role of each user in a unit. See Laravel Mant to Many documentation for more details.
You don't have to use a role table though, a simple enum would probably be just fine for your role options ie "owner" and "reader".
P.S. I am also assuming you have unit_id in your unit_user table as well.
